# Calling next image in collectionview from other class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, instagram-api

I built an app that fetch all the photos from Instagram user via Instagram API and show them ordered in CollectionView.

Now, when the user tap on a photo the photo will open in a `UIView` to show that image - basically the user can pinch to zoom and other options that can't be in the Instagram app.

What I'm trying to do is - swipe the image to move to the next image.
I thought about using ScrollView which is not a big deal.

**THE PROBLEM IS** that I don't know how to call the next photo in the collection view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegation something like this, have your view displaying the image call nextPhoto() when need an the collection view will supply.

```
        struct Photo {
            var image:UIImage?
        }

        class CustomCollectionView: UICollectionViewController{
            var dataSource:[Photo]! = []
            var selectedIndex:NSIndexPath!

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
            }
        }

        extension CustomCollectionView: UpdatePhoto {

            func nextPhoto() -> Photo?{
                let nextIndex = selectedIndex.row + 1
                 // update selected index

                selectedIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: nextIndex, inSection: 0)
                return dataSource[selectedIndex.row];
            }

            func previousPhoto() -> Photo? {
                let previousIndex = selectedIndex.row - 1
                // update selected index
                selectedIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: previousIndex , inSection: 0)
                return dataSource[selectedIndex.row];
            }
        }

        protocol UpdatePhoto {
            func nextPhoto() -> Photo?
            func previousPhoto() -> Photo?
        }
    class PhotoDisplayingView:UIView{
        var photo:Photo
        var delegate:UpdatePhoto?

        required init(photo:Photo){
            self.photo = photo
            super.init(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: photo.image!.size))
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
                fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
            }
        }
     }
```

You'll do something like this when handling the gesture
`var nextImage = delegate.nextPhoto()`

Comment: Don't think you understood me.
All I need is to take the indexpath of the photos in array and use them in other class.

Comment: I have updated it, You can either go with the new update or just pass the datasource an selected index to the photo displaying the image

Comment: Well, I try to understand how to call the nextPhoto function, to add it as subview to the ScrollView so it will show as when the system recognize UISwipeGestureRecognizer.
For somehow, I can't figure out how to call it as an UIView or UIImageView

Comment: They way I'll do this is to use a `UIPageViewController` this will take care of all the swiping and loading. But if you insist on using scroll view, when you present the first photo and the user swipes, on change, on the swipe gesture, increase the content size of the scroll view and add it right next to the photo displaying Tip: Load the next image along with current image when user swipe load the next and keep it off screen until needed. eg  [showing][notShowing] -> [notShowing][showing][notShowing]

Answer (score 0):

just store selected index path. Next photo will be next index path.

Example:
`self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath` - save

Then get next index path or nil (if not exist):

```
func nextIndexPath() -> NSIndexPath? {
  if collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(selectedIndexPath.section) > selectedIndexPath.item {
      return NSIndexPath(forItem: selectedIndexPath.item + 1, inSection: selectedIndexPath.section)
  }
  return nil
}
```

Then you could use it to get next photo, something like this:

```
if let indexPath = nextIndexPath() {
  let photo = photos[indexPath.item]
}
```

P.S. `item` is the same as `row`, but for CollectionView, because `row` wrong name for it. So it's preferable to use `item` in collection views

Comment: Can't find the member numberOfItemsInSection on my collectionview class when trying to call it.
Maybe need to register the class?